# Identity server 4 : custom token generation

Tags: identityserver4

Is there any way to override identity server 4 token generation ? means a class or interface to get username and password to call an external services to get token then use it by identity server 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then Yes, there are a couple of options.

You can create a custom ProfileService to call your external service when Claims are generated, you can then fetch data from you external service, then return a `List<Claim>` for the information you are interested in. You would write all that inside the `GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)` method.

Then you register the profile service through identity server builder middleware

```
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();  
identityServerBuilder.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
```

And when you use the access token i.e communication to a third party API, you can simply depend on `HTTPContext` to find a claim by name and get the value you need, i usually write a ClaimsProvider that has getter methods to return the claims i need and means i can mock it easily without having to consider mocking httpcontext. Something like this

[image]

It is possible to hook into the other parts of the lifecycle, check this for example: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/custom_token_request_validation.html I recommend that you read the documentation if this doesn't move you forward?

Have fun! :)